# Java JPA nested objects all having 0 for foreign key value

Tags: java, jpa

I have a database where I have a One-To-Many nested object within a given entity defined below:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentID", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<ZipEntity> zipCodesServiced;
```

I am trying to persist the parent object and this child list objects where they are linked with the parent object, but the parentID column on all created objects are "0". An example of created zipcode entries are below:

```
ID      parent_id   zipCode
2087    0           12345
2086    0           54321
```

Below is the `ZipEntity` class,

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="zip_codes_serviced")
public class ZipEntity implements Serializable {
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long ID;

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="parent_id")
private int parentId;

@Column(name="zipcode")
private String zipCode;
}
```

I don't need these fields to auto increment, I need the parent_id column to be the same for all entries created under the same parent object and to link to said parent.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my previous answer was not answering the question, it was trying to answer another question.

What I have done using this was involved three tables,

The parent table

The join table

The child table

Within the join table exists the relationships

```
  Parent ID - Child ID
         1  | 23
         1  | 46
         1  | 100
       100  | 23
```

So, the zip code child table would have its own pk I'd along with he parent table, and just the pk ids of each table get inserted to the join table, and inside of the @OneToMany you map the inverse column to the join column

Comment: So you created a reference table between the parent and child? What is the benefit of this vs having direct reference to each other with a primary/foreign key setup? Also, how would this fix the issue of the child objects being stored as null when being created via Java JPA?

Comment: 1. "What is the benefit of this vs having direct reference to each other with a   
     primary/foreign key setup?"  a. '@OneToMany' forces you to use a join table  b. how else will you store the relationships?  
 c. there is a foreign/primary key set up like this     
     
     parent  pk <--->  fk join table fk <---> pk child     

2. "how would this fix the issue of the child objects being stored as null when being created via Java JPA?"  

  a. I believe its being stored as null because the '@OneToMany' is not being used right

Comment: @OneToMany can be used together with another annotation    
`@OneToMany  
 @JoinTable(name = "<join table name>", // name = table name from db
 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "<pk of parent>"), inverseJoinColumns = 
         @JoinColumn(name = "pk of child"))`